# Need to avoid manual clicking GETNEWACCESSTOEKEN Button in postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, postman-collection-runner, postman-pre-request-script, postman-newman

My current project is Oauth 2.0 autho based.At postman,I can generate accesstoken using #Getnewaccesstoken button for my collection.

I dont want to click the generate token button in every time...Is any option there in prerequiste script form for automating this step...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an `access token` to assign `variable`.

### Your current using token

This is demo, current you use "Get New Access Token"
I am using Keycloak v.18, getting token as admin

[image]

### New method using variable

You can make own POST call for getting `access-token` and then assign same name variable.
Before your API call, you needs this code in `Tests` section.

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("access-token", jsonData.access_token);
```

[image]

POST call, your token URL and key/value for your inputs.

If you success, will get response in body
[image]

### How to use it in other API call.

In the `Authorization` tab, select `Bearer Token` Type

[image]

And Add this code. it is access token.

```
{{access-token}}
```

Then you can call any API like this.
Will get the result
[image]